# Strange behavior when joining dataframes by index in pandas. Can someone explain what is happening?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to use a Dataframe to store data before I need to output it to a file and found some strange behavior when I try and add data to the Dataframe.  Can someone please look at the code below and explain to me what is happening and let me know how I can do what I want.

The key is I need to combine the data quickly so I thought moving the data from one dataframe to another would be the fastest.

UPDATED for 0.13.0 but still getting NaN values

```
import pandas as pd; from random import uniform

pd.__version__
Out[2]: '0.13.1'

df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'x' : [int(uniform(0, 200)) for x in range(3)],
                   'y' : [int(uniform(0, 500)) for x in range(3)],
                   'z' : [int(uniform(0, 10)) for x in range(3)], 
                   'q' : [int(uniform(0, 60)) for x in range(3)],                   
                   });
df
Out[3]: 
    q    x    y  z
0  41   89  221  1
1  32   55  429  2
2   2  163  134  3

[3 rows x 4 columns]

st = pd.DataFrame({
                   'x' : [0] * 1000,
                   'y' : 0,               
                   });
st.head(2)
Out[4]: 
   x  y
0  0  0
1  0  0

[2 rows x 2 columns]

start_p = st[ st['x'] == 0].index[0];
end = start_p + len(df) -1;
print start_p, end
0 2

st.ix[start_p:end, st.columns] = df.ix[0:4,];
st.head(10)
Out[6]: 
     x    y
0   89  221
1   55  429
2  163  134
3    0    0
4    0    0
5    0    0
6    0    0
7    0    0
8    0    0
9    0    0

[10 rows x 2 columns]

df
Out[7]: 
    q    x    y  z
0  41   89  221  1
1  32   55  429  2
2   2  163  134  3

[3 rows x 4 columns]

start_p = st[ st['x'] == 0].index[0];
end = start_p + len(df) -1;
print start_p, end
3 5

st.ix[start_p:end, st.columns] = df.ix[0:4,];
st.head(10)
Out[9]: 
     x    y
0   89  221
1   55  429
2  163  134
3  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN
5  NaN  NaN
6    0    0
7    0    0
8    0    0
9    0    0

[10 rows x 2 columns]
```

Thanks

Comment: looks like a bug from a previous version; what version are you using?

Comment: works fine in 0.13.1; IIRC this was fixed in 0.12.

Comment: Good catch Jeff,  I have updated to 0.13.1 and now I get NaN values.  Is this what you got?

Comment: yep the dtype changes (which is correct)

Comment: This may need a little explanation.  Why does the dtype change to float when same data (Int64) is added into a different location in the dataframe.  What I would like to happen is the data to be added to the end.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @user1204369 you can't have NaNs in an integer field as NaN is inherently a float value.

Comment: you can try append or concat. you are doing an assignment.

Comment: I'm worried that append and concat will be to slow.  I may try reindex the smaller dataframe and work for there.  It seems that if I reindex to match the st dataframe it works fine.